# How to check if there are only defined symbols in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if string contains only predefined list of symbols and doing something like:

```
my_string = 'qwer123asd!@#$%^'
tmp = str.maketrans({'0': None, 'x': None, '#': None, '$': None, 'q': None, 'i': None})
if my_string.translate(tmp) == '':
    print("Only predefined symbols!")
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_string = 'qwer123asd!@#$%^'
predef = set('0x#$qi')

if set(my_string).issubset(predef):
    print "only predefined symbols"
```

Comment: This is neat. You can also use `set(my_string) - predef` to get the characters that are not in the predefined set, which could make error-handling easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm often advocating alternatives to regexp, since I think it is often used as a solution looking for a problem, but in this case I think it may be appropriate.

```
import re
pat = re.compile("^[0x#$qi]*$")
my_string = 'qwer123asd!@#$%^'
if pat.match(my_string):
    print("Only predefined symbols!")
```

Just make sure that if `"]"` is one of your predefined symbols it is the first symbol inside the square brackets.

A quick comparison with the set method of euromino shows that this is 3 times faster, using the strings you've used in your question. The creation of `pat` and `predef` was excluded from the timing, so this is the "repeated use" scenario. If you include them, the difference is less, but regexp is still faster.

Comment: This may be faster, but I see a possible error source in the creation of `pat`, where you have to implement the right positioning of possible appearance of `]`. Also if `^` is contained, it cannot be at the first position and `"` has to be escaped and maybe there's still something we forgot. Too complicated if the list of predefined symbols changes during the execution.

Comment: Timeit shows [@eumiro's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10311693/78845) to run in 80% of the time of yours on my laptop.

Comment: @eumiro You're right, these are valid and important concerns, and one of the reasons I'm sceptical of using regexps if I can avoid it.

Comment: @Johnsyweb strange. I'm using python 2.7, can that be the reason? Example tests: `python -m timeit -s 'import re; a = "qwer123asd!@#$%^"; b = "0x#$qi"; p = re.compile("^[{0}]*$".format(b))' 'p.match(a)'` and `python -m timeit -s 'a = "qwer123asd!@#$%^"; b = "0x#$qi"; p = set(b)' 'set(a).issubset(p)'`

Comment: @Johnsyweb you're timing the import statement too, of course my solution will come out badly. Isn't the point to time the part that will be used repeatedly? I've now timed both solutions using somewhat random strings, paste [here](http://pastebin.com/X8ktugU3), same result.

Comment: @lazyr: Fair comment, I was timing the whole lot rather than separating the computation from the setup. Apologies, yours is faster.